# UEFI variable to modify memory map

Tags: uefi, memory-mapping

I want to create a variable that the UEFI firmware will use to automatically map out some range of memory. For example pages that had a few corrected errors but that the EFI firmware doesn't declare as Unusable (because EFI tests memory once at boot and doesn't keep persistent list of bad DIMMs)

Is there a UEFI variable that is used when the firmware is putting together the memory map?

Intel has a white paper on the subject where it's not mentioned about UEFI variables, but it's a little old (2015).

https://firmware.intel.com/sites/default/files/resources/A_Tour_Beyond_BIOS_Memory_Map_in%20UEFI_BIOS.pdf

Comment: The question in its current form is off-topic for this site (setting an evironment variable is not programming). If you are interested in ways of programmatically marking parts of the memory map as off-limits, please reword it such.